# Blob video empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, blob, getusermedia

What I'm doing here is sending *3 seconds* of continuous stream to the server as blob. The server combines all blobs stored into a single blob and sends it to the other clients connected. The client then plays the video. Everything works but the video when played is empty. Here's the code I'm using: 
Client side:

```
//sends to server
const sendBlob = async (data) => {
 //const blobText = await data.text();
 socket.emit("senderBlob", data);
};

//gets user's video
const getUserMedia = () => {
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    mediaStream = stream.getTracks()[0];
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start(3000);

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (data) => sendBlob(data.data);
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};

//received blob
socket.on("vidBlob", (recievedData) => {
  //const blob = new Blob([recievedData], { type: "video/mp4" });
  setVideoSrc(URL.createObjectURL(recievedData));
  console.log(URL.createObjectURL(recievedData));
});
```

Server side:

```
var prevBlobs = [];

const pushandGetBlob = (newBlob) => {
  prevBlobs.push(newBlob);
  const blob = new Blob(prevBlobs, {
    type: "video/mp4",
  });
  //return await blob.text();
  return blob;
};

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("senderBlob", (data) => {
    //const newBlob = new Blob([data], { type: "video/mp4" });
    const vidBlob = pushandGetBlob(data);
    console.log(vidBlob);
    socket.broadcast.emit("vidBlob", vidBlob);
  });

  socket.on("clearVideos", async (_) => {
    prevBlobs = [];
  });
});
```

httpServer.listen(8080);

Any help is appreciated!